# WebKitFormBoundary uploading a file to S3 using axios FormData

Tags: axios, multipartform-data, asyncfileupload

I am trying to upload files to S3, files are successfully uploaded and but when downloaded it contains `WebKitFormBoundary`

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrTBzWaHQntWAtZLX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

hello world
------WebKitFormBoundaryrTBzWaHQntWAtZLX--
```

Upload using axios

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.file);

this.axios.put(this.formUrl,
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        // 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
                    },
                })
                .then((res) => {
```

console.log(res)
                    }).catch((e) => {
console.error(e)
                    });

How do I remove boundary

Answer (score 25):

I faced the same issue. But the solution is simple. Here is my code I used to upload the file

```
axios({
    method: "PUT",
    url: url,
    data: fileToUpload,  // NOTE - this is the file not the FormData Object
    headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            uploadSuccess: "File upload successfull",
                error: undefined
            });
     })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log(err) 
    });
```

What really happens is **when you attach the file to FormData the FormData get serialized and that serialized data is stored in S3**. That's why the file become corrupted.

In the solution we **don't wrap the file inside a FormData object**. What we do is we **directly add the file to data attribute**. So nothing other than the file itself get serialized and stored in S3.

Hope this answer would help

Comment: For someone trying to solve it using pure ajax you need to have "false" for "processData" flag in the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day! For big files though I would like to do multipart with chunks so I can see in frontend the progress of upload. Any Idea how I could achieve this? I imagine, I could remove the multipart noise from file after upload with a trigger in lambda. But that seems to be a lot of work.